# How to change the fill color of the image of floating action button in android?

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I am learning android and wanted to know that is there any way to change the fill color of the FloatingActionButton from black to white. The vector asset I used is also in white fillcolor but still the fill color is black. I have read many articles and posts on FloatingActionButton but none of them helped me solving my problem.

##### Floating Action Button's xml code

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:tint="#ffffff"
        app:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:rippleColor="#ffffff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

##### Vector asset

```xml
<vector android:alpha="0.74" android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF" android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `themes.xml` file (path: app -> src -> main -> res -> values -> themes.xml) change the value of the item with `colorOnSecondary` from `@color/black` to `@color/white` or any color of your choice but make sure the color should be in your colors.xml else add the hexadecimal color code in your `themes.xml`. 
The `themes.xml` file will look like this

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SmartNotes" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

or in the add `app:tint` in the Floating Action Button's xml code like given below

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:tint="#ffffff"
        app:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:rippleColor="#ffffff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

Comment: You don't have to change the `colorOnSecondary` of the Theme instead set `app:tint` attribute in your fab xml code.

Comment: i don't see `app:tint` instead it is `android:tint` . namespace is different.

Comment: Thanks for a new answer It worked I will surely add it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, a vector is technically a drawing so not sure what you mean by text color.

But maybe you could be after `android:strokeColor`?

But it looks like you have a drawable assigned on the button, is the text part of the drawing? Without setting it we probably can't answer your question properly.

You might be able to play around with `tintMode` to get the affect/color applied to the text in the image only.

Comment: I wanted to change the fill color of the Floating Action Button's Image

Comment: Yeah, that take a look at the tintModes to try and get the affect you're looking for. Because since the it's technically an image resource, theme colors and fill attributes wouldn't apply to it. You might need to use a combination of a tintMode and a foreground/background tint of some sort.

Tint modes can sometimes impact non-uniform colors inside a particular layout.